# Spring quartz: start from 23:00 to 12:00

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

How to write the cron expression to :
start at 23:00 on first day then end at 12:00 on second day.

I can't verfiy this:

0 0/1 23-11 * * * ?

Please give me some advice.
thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and the only way I resolved it was to write 2 cron expressions.  23:00 to 23:59:59 and another one from 00:00 to 12:00

Comment: How you set the two expressions activated on one job?

Comment: By creating two jobs.  I didn't find a way to do it with one job.  the effect is the same though, the code getting run each hour between the start and end times